# Simple assembly division program crashing

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote a simple assembly program to do division, however when trying to compile in visual studio express I am just told that I have triggered a breakpoint and it won't compile.

Other programs have compiled fine so far and I can't see what I am doing wrong in this one.

```
    .386
    .model flat, c
    .stack 100h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
    .data
msg1fmt byte 0Ah,"%d",0
number sdword 5
divisor sdword 1
answer sdword ?
    .code
main proc
    mov eax, number
    cdq
    idiv divisor
    mov answer, eax
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, answer
main endp
    end
```

Comment: Breakpoint triggering != won't compile != program crash. Which one is it?

Comment: A breakpoint triggers preventing it from compiling or running. Clicking continue has no result and I can only click break.

Comment: So click break. Where does it break?

Comment: at main I think...it says there is no source available for the current location

Comment: one copy is running but I cant end the process. Just the number 5 is printed out.

Comment: You're missing a return instruction (`ret`) or a call to some exit function.